# TypeError: hbs is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, web, express-handlebars, hbs

I was doing a nodejs based project using express and when I was adding partials to the app.js file. I got a type error: `TypeError: hbs is not a function`. I installed `npm express-handlebars` module. then also showing error again. how to fix it.
i also add this code: `'var hbs=require('express-handlebars')`;'https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hMtT.png

this is my code:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defualtLayout : 'layout' , layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it doesn't look that you are initializing it in the right way cf.https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try this:

change `hbs({extname:` to `hbs.engine({extname:`

Change this

```js
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defualtLayout : 'layout' , layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}));
```

To this:

```js
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine({extname: 'hbs', defualtLayout : 'layout' , layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}));
```